# Fetch rows with DATE

Tags: mysql

I am storing rows with MySQL using a date col. Everytime I insert a new row I use date=CURDATE() .
Is there anyway I can run a SELECT statement that selects all rows that were created within the last 24 hours?

Joel

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do the same with a DATETIME object?

Comment: I believe it does work for DATETIME as well since NOW() returns a date in DATETIME format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sub_date()` function with `interval` to make a range of dates between now and 24 hours ago:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    table WHERE 
        date_field BETWEEN curdate() AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```